# Meta Reputation Points Different In Mobile App Than Web

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

In the web version of Meta Stack Overflow I have 2074 reputation points:

[image]

But in the mobile app I have 1705 reputation points:

[image]

Is there a reason for this difference or is this a bug?

Comment: Is the app built off the API? If so I believe the API is heavily cached.

Comment: @Script47 Well, according to Rich's profile 1.7k rep has been reached and surpassed around July this year. Must be pretty strong caching :D.

Comment: @Tom heh, never noticed that.

Comment: Aren't the mobile apps essentially abandonware at this point?

Comment: @DanNeely The dedicated App for Stack Overflow is, as far as I know, but the app for Stack Exchange isn't (again: as far as I know)

Comment: The screenshot above is from Version 1.6.6.2 of the Stack Exchange iOS App.

Comment: Development of all the apps have been frozen - both the SE and SO apps.

Comment: Meta SE dupes: [Meta sites in “Your Communities” display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269/323179) & [Reputation shown for meta sites in site list dropdown is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317851/323179)

Answer (score 3):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com shows your reputation *on StackOverflow itself*. You can't usually see your meta reputation. That's because there is no *right or wrong* on Meta, so reputation does not matter, and does not increase the trust here (except for those few people that spend a lot of time here, they receive some goldbadges for their meta participation [due to their reputation]).

So actually, the app and the site are just off by 25 (2074 - 2049)  probably you received an upvote and an accepted mark in the meantime.

So actually the odd behaviour here is that the app reveals your Meta reputation (or whatever that number is). This could be seen as a feature though.

Comment: Yeah, they be pulling it from the wrong place. Meta reputation is stored, since we can see badges related to reputation like [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) are awarded here, so it must be a field somewhere.

Comment: There is definitely “wrong” on Meta...

Comment: It doesn't show your meta reputation. My SO rep is ~4.9k, and on meta SO I probably would have 20k+ reputation (I have hit the reputation cap here on over 60 days, which is 12k+ reputation). However, the app shows ~4.6k rep. It's just an old rep total that I had on SO at one point.

Comment: @codyGray then what is it?

Comment: @laurel ^^  ...  .

Comment: For me, the value that it shows is probably from some time in 2018. Also note that you can reproduce this exactly on the website by clicking "edit" next to "My Communities" in the right hand dropdown.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t mean *this* answer is wrong. I don’t really know what is causing this reputation discrepancy, because I never once used the mobile apps. But your theory is valid. What I meant was just a flippant response to your claim that *”there is no right or wrong on Meta”*. There definitely are wrong things that exist on Meta.